# SQL Server 2014 - localhost port?

Tags: sql-server

I've installed a SQLServer 2014 in a Windows10 box. I'm new to MSSQL administration. I've connected successfully to the instance with Server Management, and processes are running, but I'm unable to connect to instance from a java tool. I've configured instance port manually:

[image]

Then I've checked with resource monitor and I'm not able to identify the process queue SQLSERVER is running and seems that port 1433 is not listening for connections.

So, when I try to connect from java tool I'm getting the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieRvJ.png)

Any idea?

Comment: The two images are the same: the Java tool error. But it is telling you enough:  either the SQL Server is not listening on port 1433, or the SQL Service isn't running. Make sure the service actually is started, and correct the port it is listening on.

Answer (score -1):

You can enable the TCP/IP connection or can change the port for the SQL server from the SQL  Server Configuration Manager. You can check it [here.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.